# Django connection mysql error, showing the target computer actively refused

Tags: python, django

**Problem Description：**

I am using django to connect to mysql. After clicking and executing, I am telling me that the error is that the target computer actively refuses. I would like to ask what caused this. I checked a lot of information. Basically, the service is not open, but My current mysql on my local computer is turned on.

**Error message：**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001C834726840>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\env\webnev\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 582, in connect
    **kwargs)
  File "e:\python\pytho3.6\Lib\socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "e:\python\pytho3.6\Lib\socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Unable to connect because the target computer actively refused.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

I am not sure if it is related to the version of the module, but as long as I remove the code to add the linked database, this project will run normally.

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'POST': '3307',
    },
}
```

[image]

Comment: MySQL server not running on localhost? Firewall?

Comment: Mysql is on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the config you wrote `POST` instead of `PORT`. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is: some ports of django are bound, or the port is changed. Try changing the port to 3306.
When I changed the port in mysql to 3306, django was changed to the corresponding 3306, and I can connect.